# Configuring Keyclock 22.0.4 as a key manager in WSO2 APIM

Tags: keycloak, wso2-api-manager

```
[2024-03-29 11:11:32,491] ERROR - AccessTokenGenerator Error occurred when generating a new Access token. Server responded with 400
[2024-03-29 11:11:32,646] ERROR - APIUtil Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401 Unauthorized] during [POST] to [http://0.0.0.0:8080/realms/master/clients-registrations/openid-connect] [DCRClient#createApplication(ClientInfo)]: [{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Failed decode token"}]
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:215) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:185) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:98) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:141) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:91) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.9.1.jar:?]
    at jdk.proxy35.$Proxy467.createApplication(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.keycloak.client.KeycloakClient.createApplication(KeycloakClient.java:134) ~[keycloak.key.manager_2.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:153) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:120) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:77) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody106(APIConsumerImpl.java:2313) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.28.116.76.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:788) ~[?:?]
```

I'm getting above error when configuring keyclock as a Key Manager in WSO2 APIM. I have doubled check the URLS in keymanager also and gone through this blog [text](https://medium.com/@nelconcr/troubleshooting-keycloak-as-the-keymanager-in-wso2-api-manager-4-2-0-56bcf209e016) also. But not solved. I'm using WSO2 APIM 4.2.0.